# PowerShell and XML

Tags: xml, powershell

Using PowerShell I would like to create the equivalent XML object:

```
<MainNode Name="MainNodeName" MainAttribute="0.12.3">
    <ChildNode1>ABC</ChildNode1>
    <ChildNode1>DEF</ChildNode1>
    <ChildNode2>HIJ</ChildNode2>
</MainNode>
```

My goal: I want to reuse some PowerShell scripts that take in a `System.Xml.XmlElement` but simply feed it a hard coded version.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?  Are you just trying to create the xml listed?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the node in a placeholder document root:

```
$XmlDocument = [xml]@"
<root>
  <MainNode Name="MainNodeName" MainAttribute="0.12.3">
    <ChildNode1>ABC</ChildNode1>
    <ChildNode1>DEF</ChildNode1>
    <ChildNode2>HIJ</ChildNode2>
  </MainNode>
</root>
"@

$MainNodeElement = $XmlDocument.root
```

and then pass `$MainNodeElement` as an argument to your existing functions/scripts